# Apache CXF Jax-rs server generated from API spec using Swagger 2.0, what do I need to add to get this working?

Tags: rest, jax-rs, cxf, swagger-2.0

I have generated Apache CXF JAX-RS REST api server side code using Swagger 2.0 specification thus created with CXF version 3.1.8 dependencies. I want to understand what is the next step in order to get a REST application server running(standalone Jetty or Spring Boot or Tomcat). I am specifically looking for maven dependencies involved + configurations I need to add. I found it difficult to gather the correct details from available documentation as is it brief.

I tried following the CXF samples but keep running into issues for eg:

```
Mar 07, 2017 4:57:53 PM org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils readFromMessageBody
WARNING: No message body reader has been found for request class ABC, ContentType : application/json.
Mar 07, 2017 4:57:53 PM org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.WebApplicationExceptionMapper toResponse
WARNING: WebApplicationException has been caught : no cause is available
```

I am finding it difficult to understand the dependencies because of involvement of Swagger. The sample code works fine but not with the one generated with Swagger, when I use it, it gives above exception.

I want to understand the next steps and would appreciate if anyone who has done it with Swagger can help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`No message body reader has been found` Generally occurs when you have not registered providers.

```
@Bean
public JacksonJsonProvider jacksonJsonProvider(){
    return new JacksonJsonProvider();
}
```

Here is complete Spring boot configuration for CXF with Swagger2.

**Updated Pom.xml with CXF related dependency**

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-spring-boot-starter-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.10</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1-1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-rs-service-description</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.10</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars.bower</groupId>
            <artifactId>angular-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>0.4.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>webjars-locator</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars.bower</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrap-less-only</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-rs-service-description-swagger</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.10</version>
        </dependency>
```

**Note: Since I'm using angular-swagger-ui added additional dependency**

**Configure CXF Beans.**

```
@Configuration
public class CxfConfig {

    @Bean
    public Swagger2Feature swagger2Feature(){
        Swagger2Feature feature = new Swagger2Feature();
        feature.setPrettyPrint(true);
        feature.setUsePathBasedConfig(true);
        feature.setScan(false);
        feature.setBasePath("/swagger");
        return feature;
    }

    @Bean
    public JacksonJsonProvider jacksonJsonProvider(){
        return new JacksonJsonProvider();
    }

}
```

**Enable cxf component auto scan in application.properties**

```
cxf.jaxrs.component-scan=true
```

Create html file apidoc.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/webjars/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="/webjars/angular-swagger-ui/dist/css/swagger-ui.min.css">
<script src="/webjars/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="/webjars/angular-swagger-ui/dist/scripts/swagger-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="/webjars/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
<script src="/webjars/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/webjars/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/cxf.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="cxfApp" ng-controller="cxfCtrl" >
    <div swagger-ui url="cxfUrl" api-explorer="true" validator-url="false"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

**Enable angular-swggaer in cxf.js**

```
angular.module('cxfApp', ['ngSanitize', 'swaggerUi']).controller("cxfCtrl", function($scope) {

    $scope.cxfUrl = '/services/swagger.json';

})
```

Now on starting spring-boot application. Verify the following.

> http://localhost:8080/services?_wadl 
>      
> For WADL file
>   http://localhost:8080/services/swagger.json
>      
> For Swagger JSON File
>   http://localhost:8080/.html
>      
> For angular-swagger-ui

Comment: Thank you for replying Karthik. I will refer to these dependencies and crosscheck. I have decided to break this into two parts, Spring Boot and Apache CXF, as it seems a lot of stuff available on web assumes knowledge about either of these so it is not very detailed. I did get the war working eventually for an embedded tomcat, but I want to do this with Spring Boot as I have a Spring Boot REST api code ready and I want to compare the two frameworks.

Comment: Thanks Karthik, yes one of the things I was missing was  the bean definition for JacksonJsonProvider.

Answer (score 0):

Spring boot application

```
@ComponentScan("com.example")
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={MongoAutoConfiguration.class})
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringBootCXFServer {

    @Autowired
    private Bus bus;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootCXFServer.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public Server rsServer() {
        JAXRSServerFactoryBean endpoint = new JAXRSServerFactoryBean();
        endpoint.setBus(bus);
        endpoint.setServiceBeans(
                Arrays.<Object>asList(new DevicesLoggersApiServiceImpl(), new DevicesLoggersEntriesApiServiceImpl()));
        endpoint.setAddress("/services/");
        endpoint.setFeatures(Arrays.asList(new Swagger2Feature()));
        return endpoint.create();
    }

    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean
    public JacksonJsonProvider jsonProvider(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
        JacksonJaxbJsonProvider provider = new JacksonJaxbJsonProvider();
        provider.setMapper(objectMapper);
        return provider;
}

}
```

And pom.xml:

```
<!-- Inherit defaults from Spring Boot -->
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.8.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>


    <!-- <dependencyManagement> <dependencies> <dependency> Import dependency 
        management from Spring Boot <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId> 
        <version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version> <type>pom</type> <scope>import</scope> </dependency> 
        </dependencies> </dependencyManagement> -->
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>integration-test</goal>
                            <goal>verify</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.9.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>add-source</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>add-source</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sources>
                                <source>src/gen/java</source>
                            </sources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <!-- build WAR file -->
            <!-- <plugin> <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId> <version>2.1.1</version> 
                <configuration> <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml> </configuration> 
                </plugin> -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>com.example.Main</mainClass>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
<dependencies>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.8.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.all.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/jul-to-slf4j <dependency> 
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId> <artifactId>jul-to-slf4j</artifactId> <version>${slf4j.all.version}</version> 
            </dependency> -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-slf4j-impl -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
            <version>${swagger-core-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>${junit-version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Bean Validation API support -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>${beanvalidation-version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- CXF Client -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-rs-client</artifactId>
            <version>${cxf-version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- CXF server -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>${cxf-version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-rs-service-description</artifactId>
            <version>${cxf-version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-rs-service-description-swagger</artifactId>
            <version>${cxf-version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-ws-policy</artifactId>
            <version>${cxf-version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-wsdl</artifactId>
            <version>${cxf-version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs/jackson-jaxrs-json-provider -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-spring-boot-starter-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.10</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
```

Comment: You don't need to define JaxrsServerFactoryBean, Autowire Bus etc. if you use cxf-spring-boot-starter-jaxrs dependency. Its a cool way to integrate cxf with spring-boot. Add the maven dependency enable cxf by property cxf.jaxrs.component-scan=true in application.properties and annotate your service class with @ Component/@ Serverice and @ Path. Spring boot does everything for you. Below Example I had added is part of that.

Comment: Thanks Karthik for letting me know, I was having multiple issues and this is the resultant working code. I will try out your suggestions for sure but I am inclined to go towards Spring completely because contract first is working well with Swagger 2.0 and Spring. The jax-rs cxf codegen has missing things like Json type hierarchy tags so we are mostly not going for CXF.