# Swagger, CXF and Servicemix

Tags: swagger, cxf, apache-servicemix

How to include swagger for rest services created using cxfrs and What all features and bundles required to run it in servicemix?

Comment: Particularly in servicemix 7

Comment: I'm not aware of servicemix, but cxf with swagger an example is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42654231/apache-cxf-jax-rs-server-generated-from-api-spec-using-swagger-2-0-what-do-i-ne/42689776#42689776

Comment: @KarthikPrasad Where you able to find a solution for this?